# Visual Studio 2013 button to add a View is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

After creating a few views, the **AddView>Add button became disabled** and I can't add views anymore. 
Does anyone have a hint about that?

[image]

**EDIT**

I can add views using the *Add New Item* command and selecting *Views*, but it's nonsense to me.

Comment: Already did a lot of times. Restarted the PC too! :(

Comment: Same for me.. did you find a solution.

Comment: @Sanj just some kind of strange behavior. Creating another project works again. Isnt the right to do, but few hours later, it come back working. I dont know why :(

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes yeah it started working for me as well. Not sure what was the cause and how exactly to replicate constantly.

Comment: Same problem for me, I think this could be related to some plugins! VS2013 Premium!

Comment: @Djavier89 Pretty sure! I was using Premium too. After the SO reinstall (for other reasons) I installed the VS Professional. The issue never appears again.

Comment: I got the same problem.  Using professional version.  My third party plugins are Resharper and Stylecop.

Comment: I have added a solution below which worked perfectly for me. Hopefully it works for everyone else with this issue too :)

Comment: A simple restart of visual studio fixed error for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466961/194721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may well have solved this by now, but I thought I'd add my answer for others suffering with this issue.

This same issue happened to me, and the solution was to edit the .csproj file to tell Visual Studio that it was an MVC project.

**Here's what you do:**

1) Open up the .csproj file of the MVC project in a text editor (Notepad is fine).

2) Find the tag .

3) For visual Studio 2013 it should read like this (may work for 2012 also):

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

4) Save the changes - Visual Studio will detect them and re-load the project.

**Here's why you do it:**

All that line in the .csproj file does is tells Visual Studio which type of project it is.

E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47 = ASP.NET MVC 4.0

349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21 = Web Application

fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc = C#

In your case, I expect E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47 is missing, so VS doesn't know that it's an MVC project, therefore won't allow you to add Views and Controllers.

You can look up the various guids here in case you ever need them. http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

I hope this is a help to you.

Comment: Looks something interesting, but I can't reproduce anymore! :( I don't know if it will work

Comment: A simple restart of visual studio fixed error for me

Answer (score 0):

It seem that one of update for visual studio is not installed completely. 
you can uninstall visual studio or re-install last update.