# Cannot add view to ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add a view to an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2013, but the Add button is greyed out.

[image: vs 2013 cannot add view]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435315/visual-studio-2013-button-to-add-a-view-is-disabled

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using premium, it happens also after restart of vs2013. Reinstalling VS for this annoyance is too much work so i'll work around it untill someone finds a solution

Comment: install the latest updates and remove any third party extensions

Comment: This is funny. I disabled a number of extensions, then restart VS and I was able to add views again. Then I re-enabled the extensions one by one to find out which one was causing the problem, but after enabling all of them (and restarting in the mean time) it still works... So for some reason, disabling and enabling extensions worked in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

The default installation of Visual Studio was missing some required elements.  When I chose ASP.NET and web development, the following options were not selected on the right side of the page.

- .NET Framework project and item templates
- NET Framework 4.6.2-4.7.1 development tools
- Additional Project templates (previous versions)
- .NET WebAssembly build tools

(I found this on the Microsoft web site [Microsoft Developer Resources](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-Add-View-to-MVC-project-doesnt-/1577500) (in spanish!)
[image]

Comment: Also solution for Visual Studio 2022 Comunity Version, work perfect, Thk.

Comment: Worked for me in 2022 Com as well!

Comment: Find it here in VS menu: Tools -> Get Tools and Features

Comment: They make me pull my hair out all day to save 2 MB?

Answer (score 1):

I got this for ages, all I did was upgrade the nuget packages for Mvc and it fixed it.  I suspect that I had a mismatch of versions in the solution.

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

The version part is optional, but it should mean that all projects get the same version.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a controller first, then it will create a View folder automatically. Try to right click that file then click create new view. Also Copy might be a specific name, you may need to change that name.

Answer (score -2):

Different from the OP issue (as I'm on VS2017) but in case anyone else comes to this question when they've made the same (basic) error as me...

It took me a few minutes to realise that if you type in a new Model class (as seen below) then this is not what the UI wants; it requires you to select an existing Model from the dropdown. Once I created the model and then selected it 'Add' was enabled.

[image]

Comment: At least you could modify the model field.