# adding view is disabled in VS 2015 MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have a working MVC 5 web application. everything was ok until suddenlly i found out that i cannot add a view to the application and the add button is disabled.

[image: Adding a view button is disabled]

- I use VS 2015 Entrprise update 3 RC.
- C# as a programming language.

the project type GUIDS tag looks like this

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

please help me with this.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you already have another View named "View"?

Comment: the image is just for reference, i tired any name, same thing

Answer (score 1):

Your `ProjectTypeGuids` look ok. You can view a list of ProjectTypeGuids [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs).

I have `Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition` here and it works fine when I try to add a `View` clicking on `Views folder` and an `Action` inside a `Controller`.

There are some similar questions here at stackoverflow, maybe they can help you:

- [Cannot add view to ASP.NET MVC 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454808/cannot-add-view-to-asp-net-mvc-5-project)
- [Visual Studio 2013 button to add a View is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435315/visual-studio-2013-button-to-add-a-view-is-disabled)

Can you give more information about how you are trying da add that `View` please?

#### Some tests

I can reproduce clicking on the `Views` folder and the add button is disabled if I choose `Template: Empty` and don't select any `Model Class`:

[image]

The only way the button `Add` will be enabled with no `Model Class` selected is if I choose `Empty (Without Model)`:

[image]

Comment: i just right-click on the views folder and point to add and click view

Comment: i've added some tests and examples

Comment: There is no Template option in the add view window !!

Comment: i tried another option: add MVC 5 Partial Page (Razor). I do not know the difference, but any way it is a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the following installed:
[Modifying VS -> workloads -> installation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoHeM.png)